# find variable on an other one with powershell using substring

Tags: powershell, powercli

I want to check if the content of variable A is present in the content variable B with powershell:

```
variable A = PROD 
variable B = xxxxxPRODxxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use -match to compare using regex

```
$keyword = 'PROD'
$string = 'xxxxxPRODxxxxx'
if($string -match $keyword){write-host 'matched'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use the `String.Contains()` method:

```
$A = 'PROD'
$B = 'xxxxPRODxxxx'
$B.Contains($A)
```

or use the `-like` operator:

```
$B -like "*$A*"
```